# Access multiple pivot tables with one eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Contrived example: go!

Say I have a `Dog`.

This `Dog` can be owned by `User`s and `Company`s, any number of each. (It's a lovable dog).

So we're working with 5 tables so far:

- companies
- dogs
- dog_company
- dog_user
- users

Now, to complicate things, each pivot table has an extra field or two. Let's say the the Companies track the dog's shot records `is_shotted` and the Users track his feeding `is_fed`.

Assuming I have the relationships set up properly on User, Company, and Dog, I can do:

```
$users->dogs()->first()->pivot->is_fed
```

to access one pivot table and

```
$companies->dogs()->first()->pivot->is_shotted
```

to access the other.

But how do I access both? I want a way to retroactively "activate" a relationship. Something like this only better:

```
$dog = $users->dogs->first();
$is_fed = $dog->pivot->is_fed;
$dog->addPivot( $company );
$is_shotted = $dog->pivot->is_shotted;
```

Is there any way to do this without doing raw DB queries on the pivot table? I *really* want to avoid that, it makes things very messy sometimes.

As an consolation alternative: is there a "right" way to add data onto a model, properties that aren't on the table, that will persist through the request and will still be `toArray()`ed? (I can modify the accessor if needed.)

Comment: Why would you store `is_shot` and `is_fed` on the pivot tables? Or is it just an imaginary example?

Comment: How else would you store something that is pertinent to a many-to-many relation, yet not specific to each side? (In OP's example—which is contrived—`is_fed` is specific only to the relation between `user` and `dog`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the `$dog` object, call your `dog_company` inverse relation, i.e. `$dog->companies()->first()->pivot->is_shotted` to work backwards from dog up to company. Or if the dog can belong to multiple companies, `$dog->companies` would retrieve them all, and you would need to decide which company to check `is_shotted` on.

---

If you need to retrieve `is_shotted` and `is_walked` as part of one result collection, you could use an accessor and merge the two relations. So, for instance, starting from the `dog` model, you could:

```
public function getOwnersAttribute($value)
{
    $ownerUser = $this->users;
    $ownerCompany = $this->company;

    // Return a single collection result
    return $ownerUser->merge($ownerCompany);
}
```

or, tacking additional methods on to the relations:

```
public function getOwnersAttribute($value)
{
    $ownerUser = $this->users()->latest()->get();
    $ownerCompany = $this->company()->latest()->get();

    // Return a single collection result
    return $ownerUser->merge($ownerCompany);
}
```

I would imagine you could modify this accessor to go from `user` `->` `dog` `->` `company` and merge the result into a single collection, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Holy crap, forest for the trees, there. That's so obvious. Been beating my head against the wall on this one for a week (off and on, had to let the bruises heal). Many thanks!

Comment: Actually, that gets me most of the way there, but how do I access multiple pivots *from within the Model*? Using `appends` and a custom Accessor? Is `$this->pivot` going to contain fields from both pivot tables?

Comment: If you need both pivot tables to be accessible within on collection result, you could try setting up an accessor that merges the two relations...see edited answer.

Comment: Yikes, that is messier than I'd hoped, but I might be able to work with it. Only big problem I foresee is doing eager loading, having to juggle relationship (`->latest()` will almost never be the desired element), but this gets me on track, I think.

Comment: Be careful, merging `Eloquent\Collections` overrides items with the same `id`. It's not the way.

Comment: Ah, good point @Jarek Tkaczyk. I should've tested that idea. You're the expert on tweaking Eloquent relations; how would you handle a situation like this?

Comment: Generally I can't see any reason to merge anything from 2 pivot tables, since `is_fed` and `is_shot` are (with this setup, I wouldn't do this in the first place) separate things that are relevant ONLY in the context of given relation, ie. dog-user, dog-company, not dog-user-company.

Comment: The reason this comes up, say there's a `File` object that `User` and `Company` both have one-to-many relationships to. The `User` may Star or `Company` may archive that `File`. The `File` needs to come downstream (API-style) with both `is_archived` and `is_starred` available in some way.

Comment: Do `User` and `Company` both have one-to-many or many-to-many relationships to a `File`? (i.e. can a single file belong to more than one user or more than one company?) If the relation is indeed one-to-many in both cases, it would be simpler to store `is_archived` and `is_starred` on the `File` model, with no pivot tables necessary.

Comment: Crap, typo, that's what I get from answering from my phone. They're both many-to-many, of course.